# Override POST method in Spring Data REST not allowed

Tags: java, spring-boot, post, spring-data-rest

I need to add my custom business logic for a POST method of one of my entities that is being handled with Spring Data REST. On the internet, I found out that I need to disable the `save` method (which is responsible for the entity creation) and then set up a `RepositoryRestController` that handles the new POST request. The code is the following.

Entity Repository:

```java
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface AssetRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Asset, UUID> {

    @RestResource(exported = false)
    @Override
    Asset save(Asset asset);

}
```

Custom Controller:

```java
@RepositoryRestController
public class MyEntityCustomController{

    @PostMapping(
            value = "/assets",
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<MyResource> addEntity(@RequestBody MyResource resource) {
        // create the resource with custom logic
    }

}
```

The application runs correctly but, whenever I try to send a POST request, I get the following response:

```json
{
    "code": null,
    "message": "Request method 'POST' not supported",
    "details": []
}
```

I also tried to put the `@BasePathAwareController` annotation but that didn't change much. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does this help in any way? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/issues/1356

Comment: I don't think it does, they don't specify clearly the way to override the method, and the user asking the question wants also to override a simple GET request, while I need to override the POST method.